# Can't get message from message response

Tags: python, pycord

Pycord version:
2.0.0b4

I want to make a bot that sends a message, then adds two reactions to that message when the slash command is used. I tried to get the message and add a reaction but the line `message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)` produces the error. How do I get the specific message to add the reaction in Pycord?

#### Code

```
  message = await ctx.respond(embed = embed_check)
  print(message.id)
  print(ctx.channel)
  global message_react
  message_react = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
  print(message_react)
  message_react.add_reaction("✅")
```

I tried to get the `message.id` from the response, but it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/bot.py",
 line 520, in process_application_commands
     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py",
 line 306, in invoke
     await injected(ctx)
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py",
 line 116, in wrapped
     raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application
 Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code:
 10008): Unknown Message
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
import os
import random
import asyncio

testing_servers = [912361242985918464]
intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = discord.Bot(intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online!')

@bot.slash_command(guild_ids=testing_servers, name="announce", description="Make server announcements!")
async def announce(ctx,channel_id : discord.Option(str, description = "Copy the text channel in developer mode."),title:str,text : str):
    #response embed
  try:
    channel = bot.get_channel(int(channel_id))
  except ValueError:
    channel = channel_id
    #announcement embed
  embed_check = discord.Embed(
    colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
    title = "Is this embed shown correct?",
    description = title + "\n" * 2 + text
    
  )
  
  response = await ctx.respond(embed = embed_check)
  print(ctx.channel)
  global message_react
  message_react = await response.original_message()
  print(message_react)
  await message_react.add_reaction("✅")


  embed_announce = discord.Embed(
      colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
      title=str(title),
      description = text
  )
  await channel.send(embed = embed_announce)

  embed = discord.Embed(
      colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
      title = "Sent!",
      description= "Check the channel!"
  )

  await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

This should do the trick. You should be aware that if you were to add a ctx.response.defer() this will no longer work, since ctx.respond returns a WebhookMessage instead of an Interaction, which you can't add emoji to.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you already have the right solution to fix it, just in the wrong place. Move the *try-catch* to the part where you define `message` - this can return this error. You can remind yourself that message fetching is a direct API call and can run such kinds of errors.

And `bot.get_channel` *never* returns such an error. If the bot can't find the channel with the desired ID, will `NoneType` be returned. So you should check here if the channel is `None`.

```py
# Get channel object

channel = bot.get_channel(int(channel_id))
if channel is None:
   channel = channel_id
   #announcement embed
else:
   embed_check = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.blue(),
                               title = "Is this embed shown correct?",
                               description = title + "\n" * 2 + text)

# Get message object

message = await ctx.respond(embed = embed_check)
try:
   message = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(message.id)
except discord.NotFound:
   return await ctx.respond('message not found')
```

---

### Sources

- *[get_channel(channel_id, /)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)*
- *[await fetch_message(id, /)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)*